# Convert string to int value python

Tags: python, string, int

I want to convert a string to a specific int value in Python i.e. "red" I want to be 1, "blue" to 2, etc. I am currently using if-else statements. I have a dataset of strings with common strings that I want to associate with a number. Please help.

```
def discretize_class(x):
    if x == 'first':
        return int(1)
    elif x == 'second':
        return int(2)
    elif x == 'third':
        return int(3)
    elif x == 'crew':
        return int(4)
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried?

Comment: Please add your code to do the question, not in a comment.

Comment: Use a dictionary d = {'first': 1, 'second': 2}. Than you can say d['first'] which will retun 1

Comment: how would I convert a dataset of strings to a dictionary?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a dictionary. That would be best I think:

```
dictionary = {'red': 1, 'blue': 2}
print dictionary['red']
```

Or with the new code you added just now:

```
def discretize_class(x):

    dictionary = {'first': 1, 'second': 2, 'third': 3, 'crew': 4}
    return dictionary[x]

print discretize_class('second')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, by datasets, you either mean a

- text file
- database table
- a list of strings

So first thing importantly, you need to know, how you can read the data. Example for

- test file: You can simply read the file and iterate through the file object
- database table: Based on what library you use, it would provide an API to read all the data into a list of string
- list of strings: Well you already got it

Enumerate all the strings using the built-in [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Swap the enumeration with the string

Either use dict-comprehension (if your python version supports), or convert the list of tuples to a dictionary via the built-in `dict

```
with open("dataset") as fin:
    mapping = {value: num for num, value in enumerate(fin)}
```

This will provide a `dictionary`, where each string, ex, `red` or `blue` is mapped to a unique number

Comment: so i have a dataset where the first line is "third, adult, male, yes" second line is "second, adult, female, yes", etc. I want third to equal the same int value throughout,and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but maybe this helps.

```
common_strings = ["red","blue","darkorange"]
c = {}
a = 0
for item in common_strings:
    a += 1        
    c[item] = a
# now you have a dict with a common string each with it's own number.
```